# secure button command processing in PHP

Tags: php, sql, identifier

I have a database with orders, first entry would be:

> id(int) = 1
>
> info_1(varchar) = 'one'
>
> info_2(varchar) = 'two'

I'm using a PHP scipt that itterates through orders and creates HTML buttons:

```
while ($temp = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3))
{
   echo "<button id=\"".$temp['id']."\" name=\"delete_but\">Delete</button>";
   // plus some conditions
}
```

Result:

```
<button id="1" name="delete_but">Delete</button>
<button id="2" name="delete_but">Delete</button>
<button id="3" name="delete_but">Delete</button>
...
<button id="10" name="add_but">Add</button>
<button id="11" name="add_but">Add</button>
<button id="12" name="add_but">Add</button>
...
```

**How do I create a PHP script, which will be triggered on button click?** I'd like to remove entry from Table where (id == "clicked_button_id").

Also, I'd like to know if it's secure to put Order's ID inside button's ID, because every user will be able to see the HTML of my page (along with all IDs).

Comment: Are you planning to do this with an AJAX call on button click, or by posting back to PHP so the page reloads?

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page =) so, yes , AJAX. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: Then are you planning to use plain JavaScript, jQuery, or something else?

Comment: (the PHP is the easy part here - as long as you are reading from something like `$_POST['delete_id']` and crucially, _checking that the user doing the deletion has permission to do it_.

Comment: tough question, but preference goes to jQuerry, I guess.. It's more or less the same javascript, but allows to do some cool things easily (i'm talking about fancy effects ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('button[name=delete_but]').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'deleteEntry.php?id=' + $(this).attr('id')
  }).done(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

deleteEntry.php:

```
$entryId = $_GET['id'];

// ...database work to remove the entry with that id...
```

Comment: thanks! is it secure to use this approach? I had doubts because every user could see button's ID (and also theoretically substitute this ID with any other)

Comment: @Alex No, it's not secure. You have to check that the user is logged in/has the permission to delete the entry by yourself.

Comment: @Gargron yes, you are right.. I've just hacked my own website by entering: http://sitename.net/deleteEntry.php?id=5&name=accept_but and it worked. That means - anybody can put ANY ID and remove somebody's order!

Comment: so, I've changed method to "POST" and now it's somehow harder to hack the system ;) additionally, I'll be checking if LoggedIn user has the order with "this ID" or not. If not, - I can be sure that that was a hack attempt. Any other precautions?

Comment: It is more secure to use POST because the parameters aren't being passed as plain text in the request like they are with GET. Checking that the user owns the order is good.